ByteSize comparison between primitive and wrapped types in protobuf
I am debating between using primitive type uint64 vs a wrapped version of uint64. I settled on using a wrapped type because it gives me better object handling in different languages. But when I evaluated the size of an array with uint64 vs the wrapped data type, the wrapped one was 33% larger than the primitive one.
Although I expected it to be larger, 33% larger looks a bit too extreme and I am re-considering if I should go for wrapped types or not. Can someone help me understand why wrapping bloats up the size by that much.
Edit: I used python for size comparison
